# Powershell script getting called twice from C#.net code

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, service, runspace

I have following code which I call from my C#.net service which results in calling the powershell script twice.

```
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
      runspace.Open();

      runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("scriptpath", scriptPath);
      runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("DBRecordKey", reportId.Key);
      runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("SymbolPath", symbolPath);
      Logger.Log("DBRecordKey = " + reportId.Key, writer);
      using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline(scriptText))
      {
             //Here's how you add a new script with arguments
             pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

             // Execute PowerShell script
             Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

             StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder();
             foreach (PSObject obj in results)
             {
                     outputString.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
             }
             Logger.Log("outputString 2 - " + outputString, writer);
             pipeline.Stop();
             runspace.Close();
      }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the script both in `CreatePipeline(scriptText)` and `AddScript(scriptText)`.
I'm not a Powershell user, but I'd suggest that *either* you want

```
using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
{
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
    ...
}
```

... *or* you want to remove the `AddScript` call entirely. If there's a particular reason you need `AddScript`, then creating the pipeline without the `scriptText` seems the logical approach.